# Android SDK version: configChanges and deprecated methods

Tags: android, sdk, version, android-configchanges

I am trying to build an app that will be compatible with low versions of Android.  On the other hand, I noticed that if I set the target SDK Version to a higher value (like 19), some features work better; in particular, animations are a lot smoother.  So -- the Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="19" android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

In addition, although the app knows how to restart itself, it does not fully do so.  I prefer to handle resizes without closing the app.  Therefore, I have the following in the Manifest:

```
android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|fontScale|uiMode|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection"
```

So far, so good.  Now, what do I put in the project.properties?

`target=android-19` shows a lot of warnings on deprecated methods.  If I try to fix them by using "replacement" methods, it would result in the compiled code incompatible with API-7.

`target=android-7` gives me an error in Manifest since `screenSize` and some other configuration change options aren't defined.

Advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I try to fix them by using "replacement" methods, it would result in the compiled code incompatible with API-7.

Check at runtime what the Android version is and do different things for different versions:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    // do something
}
else {
    // do something else, if needed
}
```

(where you substitute the right `Build.VERSION_CODES` value for your use case).

Comment: OK, makes sense.  I can use this approach if some deprecated method is completely killed off.  For the sake of code clarity, I do not want to explicitly use any SDKs beyond API-7.  I was wondering if there was any method that would a) keep everything compatible with API-7, b) get rid of warnings, and c) let me keep screenSize in Manifest.

Comment: @user1334767: not in any sensible fashion. You can always disable warnings.